# How to handle app lifecycle with Flutter (on Android and iOS)?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

Are there any `Activity` lifecycle methods in Flutter apps?

Like:

```
onCreate()
onResume()
onDestroy()
```

Or:

```
viewDidload()
viewWillAppear()
```

How to handle application lifecycle when making an app with Flutter?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is a method called when the system put the app in the background or return the app to foreground named [`didChangeAppLifecycleState`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver/didChangeAppLifecycleState.html).

[Example with widgets](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html):

```
  class _AppLifecycleReactorState extends State<AppLifecycleReactor> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  AppLifecycleState _notification;

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    setState(() { _notification = state; });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text('Last notification: $_notification');
  }
}
```

Also there are *[CONSTANTS](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html)* to know the states that an application can be in, eg:

1. inactive
2. paused
3. resumed
4. suspending

The usage of these constants would be the value of the constant e.g:

`const AppLifecycleState(state)`

Comment: how to finish last activity? like Splash to login

Comment: @DeepakKanyan I think this is another question and not related to this question, you can ask new one, then refere to me and I will help if I can.

Comment: @DeepakKanyan use Navigator.pushReplacement() instead of Navigator.push() , then current activity would be removed from stack

Comment: This answer not related the question

Answer (score 9):

Run the following code, press the home button and then reopen the app to see it working. There are 4 [`AppLifecycleState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html):

> resumed: The application is visible and responding to user input.
>
> inactive: The application is in an inactive state and is not receiving user input.
>
> paused: The application is not currently visible to the user, not responding to user input, and running in the background.
>
> detached:  The application is still hosted on a flutter engine but is detached from any host views.

**Null safe code:**

```dart
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    print('Current state = $state');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Flutter version 3.13 added AppLifecycleListener so now you can listen to show, pause , resume , restart etc.

```
 _listener = AppLifecycleListener(
 onShow: () => _handleTransition('show'),
 onResume: () => _handleTransition('resume'),
 onHide: () => _handleTransition('hide'),
 onInactive: () => _handleTransition('inactive'),
 onPause: () => _handleTransition('pause'),
 onDetach: () => _handleTransition('detach'),
 onRestart: () => _handleTransition('restart'),
 // This fires for each state change. Callbacks above fire only for
 // specific state transitions.
 onStateChange: _handleStateChange,
);
```

For more info check [this example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/api/lib/widgets/app_lifecycle_listener/app_lifecycle_listener.0.dart) from flutter repo

Comment: Hii, still on Detach doesn't work as an onDestroy android method . Do you know how to accomplish when the app is killed I need to change a state in Firebase(change a boolean form true to false and viceversa.) while the app is killed by the user in the background in this app lifecycle when the app is inactive and the user swipes up the app and kills it . @Praveena

Answer (score 1):

To be notified when app goes to foreground or route popped you can inherit `LifecycleState` class and override `onResume()` and `onPause()` methods. `LifecycleState` class:

```
/// Inherit this State to be notified of lifecycle events, including popping and pushing routes.
///
/// Use `pushNamed()` or `push()` method to track lifecycle events when navigating to another route.
abstract class LifecycleState <T extends StatefulWidget> extends State<T>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  ResumeResult resumeResult = new ResumeResult();
  bool _isPaused = false;

  AppLifecycleState lastAppState = AppLifecycleState.resumed;

  void onResume() {}

  void onPause() {}

  /// Use instead of Navigator.push(), it fires onResume() after route popped
Future<T> push<T extends Object>(BuildContext context, Route<T> route, [String source]) {
    _isPaused = true;
    onPause();

    return Navigator.of(context).push(route).then((value) {
        _isPaused = false;

        resumeResult.data = value;
        resumeResult.source = source;

        onResume();
        return value;
    });
}

/// Use instead of Navigator.pushNamed(), it fires onResume() after route popped
Future<T> pushNamed<T extends Object>(BuildContext context, String routeName, {Object arguments}) {
    _isPaused = true;
    onPause();

    return Navigator.of(context).pushNamed<T>(routeName, arguments: arguments).then((value) {
        _isPaused = false;

        resumeResult.data = value;
        resumeResult.source = routeName;

        onResume();
        return value;
    });
}

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      if (!_isPaused) {
        onPause();
      }
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed &&
        lastAppState == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      if (!_isPaused) {
        onResume();
      }
    }
    lastAppState = state;
  }
}

class ResumeResult {
  dynamic data;
  String source;
}
```

Also make sure to start push new routes using `push()` or `pushNamed()` method.