# How to force Flutter to set app lifecycle state

Tags: dart, flutter

As [`didChangeAppLifecycleState`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver/didChangeAppLifecycleState.html) is able to know when app lifecycle state has changed *[[#50131598](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131598/flutter-app-lifecycle-android-ios)]*; I want to force my flutter app to be in an specific lifecycle state.

Is there a method such as `setLifeCycleState(AppLifecycleState.paused);` ?

**I want to force my running app to paused itself.**

Any suggestion will be welcome !