# Applifecycle of flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to work with permissions and I want to check if user somehow try to change the permission status. What im wondering is, is swiping down the status bar change the  flutter applifecycle? If it is, what status flutter returns?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131598/how-to-handle-app-lifecycle-with-flutter-on-android-and-ios

Comment: @RohitChaurasiya i checked this but i still don't know if there is state for swipe down on status bar.

Comment: @sonelektrikci there are 4 observable event, one of them should be called whenever app goes in background due to status bas swiping.You can check example and try to check through print statements that which callback is called and If found one you can recheck the permissions in resume callback.

Comment: @SahdeepSingh Swiping down the status bar does not change the Applifecycle status

Comment: to change permission they have to leave your app, right?

Comment: @SahdeepSingh That's right for the permission but not for the location status. To open/close the locations service, user can swipe down the status bar.