# How to use flutter's App life cycle on flutter app

Tags: flutter

I used WidgetsBindingObserver in flutter foreground and background, and wrote the code to execute the desired operation.
However, when tested on the actual machine, AppLifecycleState.paused, AppLifecycleState.resumed
Neither is working.
Please let me know if there are any possible causes.

Comment: Does  [How to handle app lifecycle with Flutter (on Android and iOS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50131598/10157127) answer your quesiton?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.