# Flutter Riverpod getting data from server on lifecycle resumed

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

With this below code i'm trying to get data from server when `Flutter` lifecycle resumed, but it doesn't work for me and i'm not sure how can i resolve that

```dart
class Home extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final scaffoldKey = useMemoized(() => GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>());
    final appLifecycleState = useAppLifecycleState();
    final showLoading = useState(false);

    useEffect(() {
      ref.read(bakersProvider.notifier).send(
        method: HTTP.GET,
        endPoint: Server.$onlineBakersList,
        parameters: {},
      );
      if (appLifecycleState == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
        debugPrint('resumed');
        ref.read(bakersProvider.notifier).send(
          method: HTTP.GET,
          endPoint: Server.$onlineBakersList,
          parameters: {},
        );
      }

      return (){};
    }, [appLifecycleState]);
```

Comment: Have you have added WidgetsBindingObserver mixin and listening to the AppLifeCycle changes inside didChangeAppLifecycleState method

Comment: @SankethB.K i used `HookConsumerWidget` and i think it doesn't necessary

Comment: HookConsumerWidget is related to riverpod, but it doesn't help to listen to changes in lifecycle methods, you can cross check by printing the lifecycle method if it is changing. Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131598/how-to-handle-app-lifecycle-with-flutter-on-android-and-ios

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine...What version of `hooks_riverpod` are you using?

Comment: @Josteve `riverpod: ^1.0.3 - flutter_hooks: ^0.18.5+1 - hooks_riverpod: ^1.0.4`, could you get data from server on `lifecycle.resumed` ?

Answer (score 2):

this issue solved. [reference](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/discussions/1693#discussioncomment-3728153)

```dart
useOnAppLifecycleStateChange((pref, state) {
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    //make a request
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, I can't even use 'HookConsumerWidget', how can I get that? I tried to add flutter_hook, riverpod_hook, and more. It does not pop out on my Flutter :(